# Изменение текста внутри определённых символов (как работать с Markdown)?

Tags: javascript, html, регулярные-выражения, markdown

На многих сайтах можно увидеть такую вещь, как изменение текста внутри определённых символов. Для примера: человек пишет **тест**, а на странице это отображается как <b>тест</b>. Как происходит такая замена на JavaScript? Если я правильно понял, это делается с помощью регулярных выражений или цикла с replace. Это так?

Comment: **пример** *пример* это один из вариантов Markdown - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, делается это регулярками (по большей степени), циклов тут не надо, например:

HTML

```
<textarea id="ta" class="ta">
  *Курсивный шрифт*  
  **А это полужирный**
</textarea>
<div id="out" class="out">Вывод</div>
```

JS

```
var ta = document.getElementById('ta'),
  out = document.getElementById('out');

ta.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  var html = ta.value;

  html = html.replace(/\*\*(.+?)\*\*/g, '<b>$1</b>')
             .replace(/\*(.+?)\*/g, '<i>$1</i>')
             .replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');

  out.innerHTML = html;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/que5hsup/

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать библиотеку https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js:

```
md_content = "Hello.\n\n* This is markdown.\n* It is fun\n* Love it or leave it."
html_content = markdown.toHTML( md_content );
```